# Cast tab from command line

Tags: chromecast

Is it possible to cast a tab via the command line? I'd like to load a video up on a page and then tell google chrome to cast it.

I've looked at all the switches available to chrome.exe and am unsure of where to even start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are not able to do so from command line.